# Insert list of pictures from datatable into MS Access database, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access, datatable

I have a datatable containing several records. Each row of the datatable has a field that stores picture. When I loop through the datatable rows to insert them into a table of a database, every field of the row is saved correctly; but for every record, the picture in the first row of the datatable is saved. I traced the code and it does hit the lines that access and try to save the pictures in each row of the datatable. I am using VB.NET and the database is MS Access.

My code looks like this:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (" & _
            "[ID], " & _
            "[Name], " & _
            "[BDate], " & _
            …….
            "[TelNo], " & _
            "[Photo]) " & _
        " VALUES(" & _
            dr("ID") & ", '" & _
            dr("Name") & "', " & _
            dr("BDate") & ", '" & _
            …….
            dr("TelNo") & "', " & _
            img & ")"

    cmd.Parameters.Add(img, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = dr("Photo")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The code does exactly what you ask:

In your loop, all fields are varying following the values in your dataset row because you do this for each : `dr(thefield)`

**except** for the image because you just do this : `img` 
It is thus always the same image.

You should have something like `dr(image)` (but I doubt it work as simply)

Comment: To Thomas G. img is a parameter whose value is supposed to be provided by the statement on the next line: 
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(img, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = dr("Photo")'
We cannot directly use dr(“Photo”) in the lilst of values because it is byte array data. All elements in the command text must be String type.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself. The problem is rather subtle. In OleDbCommands, parameters are not named. Parameters are represented by ? (the question mark). In the code snippet of my question, the variable img has the value of ?, which is assigned by a statement before the loop. The value of parameters MUST be provided in the order of their appearance. I my case, there is only one parameter and I provide a single parameter by the statement:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add(img, OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = dr("Photo")
```

However, in each iteration of the loop, another parameter will be added. For the second record, the actual value of the parameter will be the second parameter , the third record will have its value at the third place, etc. Since in OleDbCommands values for parameters are identified by their order, and since there is only one parameter in my case, the picture provided first (i.e. that of the first record) is always used.
Hence the question boils down to ‘How can I provide a single parameter in each iteration?’ And the answer is to remove the parameter added by each iteration by including this precious statement:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

as the last statement in the loop.
Sorry for the lengthy explanation.